# How does Virtual I/O Core work in Vivado?

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, verilog, logic-gates, vivado

I've recently started to learn programming in Verilog by using Vivado simulator and I noticed that the testing/checking part of your Block Design plays a very important role in obtaining the final outcome. From what I learnt there are 3 debugging methods for hardware testing before downloading the bitstream into the FPGA board:

1. One involving the Virtual I/O core
2. One involving the circuit`s simulation
3. And the last one involving an Integrated Logic Analyzer(ILA)

My question is about the first one. How does it work and what are its functioning principles? I haven`t found very explicit documentation at a first glance on the Internet.

The 2 pictures below are from the lab I am working at and there I`m told that they are equivalent in some sense. Both of them have 3 inputs and one output but the difference is that the 1st one uses 3 switches for the inputs whereas the second one not. Also, I heard the VIO core is used when the input/output ports on the FPGA board are not enough.

My confusion comes firstly from the fact that in the second picture the output D is connected to the input of vio_0 and I don't understand why. It makes me think about sequential circuits but I'm not sure if that's the case (I think not).

Any explanation or further understanding of the 2 would be welcome.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my explanation of the 3:

1. circuit simulation: No real hardware involved, you are just testing your code to make sure it works properly. In theory, the real world should match the simulation if done properly.
2. ILA. Integrated Logic Analyzer. This is a way to view signals on real hardware. This is a true hardware logic analyzer (if you don't know what that its, it's just a way to view digital signals like an oscope can view electrical signals). So you have a real FPGA programmed and running, real inputs driven from either the FPGA pins or other parts of the logic, and it's generating real outputs. The ILA can view what is happening on both the inputs and outputs.
3. VIO. Instead of having real inputs driven from FPGA pins or other parts of the logic, you can now force the inputs to be whatever values you want, on real hardware, while the FPGA is running. So while the FPGA is running, someone can interact with a GUI to force the values to be whatever they want. As a bonus, you can also view the current state of signals (kind of like a multimeter). So when the 2nd image wraps D back around, that's all it is doing: Letting the value of D show up in the GUI as user feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my understanding on vio. Just think virtual IO as a black box that takes/stores the output of your circuit based on your input to your circuit.

Now in order to give input to the circuit, there must be some signal that come from the vio. So, the output of vio becomes the input of the your circuit and the output of your circuit is stored as a input in the vio with respect to your input to the circuit.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aoMdoZwbjI8

https://www.xilinx.com/products/intellectual-property/vio.html

After watching the youtube video above and rereading the Xilinx product description of the LogiCore IP Virtual Input/Output (VIO), I found very explanatory the following sentence:

> The LogiCORE™ IP Virtual Input/Output (VIO) core is a customizable core that can both monitor and drive internal FPGA signals in real time.

So basically everytime you use the VIO component for monitoring the behaviour of your circuit you must connect the output signals that you monitor to the input ports of your VIO block. Thus, later in the "hw_vios" window, where you can check your circuit, you will be able to monitor these signals because the VIO block actually receives them on the input ports.

As about the output ports of the VIO block these are actually the input signals that you want to implement and give them various values in order to test your circuit. What VIO does is to virtualize them, giving you the possibility of not using the in-board swithces anymore.